# How to implement a spellchecker algorithm for phrase suggestions in Lucene 5.2.x?

Tags: java, lucene, nlp, spell-checking

I'm working with Lucene spellchecker for spelling correction. Although the program returns similar words, it is not what I'm looking for. Any suggestions on how to get phrases returned instead of words. I have a text file with one sentence per line which is indexed and I want the program to correct the spelling and return the entire line instead of words similar to the query searched for.

Here is a code snippet of what I've done:

```
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);

    SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
    spellChecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(reader, "contents"), iwc, true);

    int numofsuggestions = 10;

    String[] suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar(query, numofsuggestions);
```